# Blender for virtual production

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, chromakey

I recently joined a virtual production company that uses UE5 to do live virtual production. Basically they use UE5 to remove green screen live. I was wonder if the same could be done in blender and i came across this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKLor-DDtdQ

But i did not understand it, nor is it too specific. Can someone explain to me how we can achieve this? Please be gentle it's my first time --learning about live chroma removal in blender.

Also is this viable in eevee?

Comment: I just want to go out and say that you'd be **much** better off learning UE5 for live virtual production than Blender. That is a major part of Unreal Engine, and Blender isn't really made for that.

Comment: @BlenderMaster15 true, i am doing just that, however i'm a blender purist, i'll use these tother tools till blender gets there... if it is possible then what would i have to do in blender, amount of effort is no issue to me just that it is possible. Sounds maniacal, i know, but just humor me XD